# How can I cleanly finish and starts rows, using single crochet, in my pokeballs?

Tags: crocheting

In my continued adventures in making pokeballs I have run into another issue that experimenting is not fixing. The balls are made just using single crochet (sc). Typically what I do for sc project row is something like this:

> - Ch 1, sc in same stitch
> - sc around
> - skip last stitch in row and sl st into first sc of row

That works well for me and looks perfectly fine on something like a [toilet paper octopus holder](http://crazycraftiness.blogspot.ca/2011/02/crazy-little-octopus.html). However once the balls are stuffed in pushes that those stitches out creating a visible raised ridge on the outside.

[image: Bottoms of my balls]

I didn't find the [instructions I was following](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pokeball-Set/), which are pretty much the same for all balls or spheres, clear on this matter.

So to try something different to see if I could avoid this I tried the following instead:

> - Ch 1, skip 1, sc
> - sc around
> - sl st into first sc of row

This fixed the issue I am describing but the row ends also biased (instead of forming a straight vertical line every row moved over one stitch). Some people might not notice this - but I do!

How else could I be doing me sc in a sphere or ball so that I clean relatively flat row ends that don't bias?

Comment: I dunno anything about crochet, but would moving the starts to the side with the ⭕ / button on the front make this less obvious?

Comment: Amigurumi is usually worked in a spiral, isn't it? That's how the octopus I made is. Though, with the hard separation between the colors, that could be problematic, too...though it might be worth exploring.

Comment: @Catija I never realized that. Never really done any Amigurumi before this. The octopus top might be done like that but I did that from assumption of how it looked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genrally in amigurumi you don't crochet in rows, but in spiral. This way there is no visible seam at all, but you usually need a stitch marker to keep track of where rows begin and end.

Here is a photo of a bottom of a bunny I made, to illustrate how it's done and looks:

[image]

Comment: I never realized that it was done in spiral. Never really done any Amigurumi before this. Thank you